# Selenium/java is returning empty text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, getattribute

I have a table and below is the description of the html-row that I am writing selenium test for:

```
<mat-row _ngcontent-kgo-c23="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" role="row">
    <!---->
        <mat-cell _ngcontent-kgo-c23="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-id mat-column-id ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell">
            <a _ngcontent-kgo-c23="" ng-reflect-router-link="/dir,208" href="/claim/208">208</a>
        </mat-cell>
        <mat-cell _ngcontent-kgo-c23="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-firstName mat-column-firstName ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell">
        George
        </mat-cell>
</mat-row>
```

Here is the test :

```
List<WebElement> idRows = super.wait(WAIT, INTERVAL).until(driver -> driver.findElements(By.className("mat-column-id")));
webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//Validate only one row exist in the search result
assertEquals(1,idRows.size());

//The result has is "208" and name "George"
WebElement firstNameInSearchResult = webDriver.findElement(By.className("cdk-column-firstName"));
System.out.println("===========>" + firstNameInSearchResult.gettext()+", " + idRows.get(0));
assertTrue(firstNameInSearchResult.getText().contains("George"));
assertTrue(idRows.get(0).getText().contains(searchId));
```

The System.out.println is showing empty text. And assertion following that print statement is failing. Am I doing the text validation in right way?

Comment: your wevDriver.findElement, is it finding the first row? Or the header row?

Comment: A row not the header row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements are [Angular](https://angular.io/) element. So to extract the text **208** and **George** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Print the text *208*:

  - Using *xpath* and `getAttribute("innerHTML")`:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//mat-cell[@class='mat-cell cdk-column-id mat-column-id ng-star-inserted']/a[contains(@ng-reflect-router-link, 'dir') and contains(@href, 'claim')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    ```
- Print the text *George*:

  - Using *xpath* and `getText()`:

    ```
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//mat-cell[@class='mat-cell cdk-column-firstName mat-column-firstName ng-star-inserted']"))).getText());
    ```